# How to execute a thread efficiently when user is continuously swiping

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager

In my app i am using view pager and fragments for swiping.In my fragment class i am using an asynctask for parsing json.so when i am continuously swiping every time this code is running in the background.but i want to execute this parsing code only when fragment is completly visible means in rest condition.so is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Check [`Activity#onUserInteraction()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onUserInteraction%28%29). This event is called when the user is interacting. You can make a timer which resets on user interaction. Only launch your JSON parser when you timer reaches a given time.

Comment: But in fragment there is no method like `onUserInteraction()` .i am launching my json Parser in my fragment class.so is there any other way to do it?@m0skit0